# awk group-by on a sub-string of a column

Tags: awk

I have the following log file:

```
/veratt/po/dashboard.do 
/veratt/po/dashboardfilter.do?view=R
/veratt/po/leaseagent.do?view=R
/veratt/po/dashboardfilter.do?&=R&=E&propcode=0&display=0&rateType=0&floorplan=&=Display&format=4&action=getReport
/veratt/po/leaseagent.do
/veratt/po/leaseagent.do?view=V
```

Desired AWK output of Count of each of the HTTP request (minus the request parameters)**

```
/veratt/po/dashboard.do  - 1
/veratt/po/leaseagent.do - 3
/veratt/po//veratt/po/dashboardfilter.do  - 2
```

I know  basic AWK command using an array - but the desired output is quite different from what I need.

```
awk  '{a[$2]=a[$2]+1;} END {for( item in a) print item , a[item];} '
```

Comment: Is the missing `?` from the dashboardfilter.do line legit or a typo?

Comment: its a typo sorry - will update it

Comment: Awk has `+=` and `++` for incrementing.

Comment: or `sed /[?].*//' logfile file2 | sort | uniq -c` ? Puts the Count at the front of the line. Easier to read IHMO ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F\? '{ count[$1]++} 
          END { for (item in count)
                  printf("%s - %d\n", item, count[item]) }' logfile
```

- `-F`: separate fields on `?` character, so `$1` is the request; it there are URL parameters they are in `$2`, whose existence we ignore. Note: could be done using `BEGIN { FS="?" }`. Note: if `FS` is more than one character, it is treated as a regex.
- `{ count[$1]++ }`: for each line, tally up the occurrence count of `$1`.
- `END`: run this block at the end of processing all the inputs
- `for (item in count)`: iterate the `item` variable over the keys in the `count` array.
- `printf("%s - %d\n", item, count[item])`: formatted printing of the item and its count, separated by a dash with spaces. Note: `%d` can be replaced by `%s`; awk is weakly typed.

Comment: You will want to quote the question mark (`-F'?'`) -- it's a glob wildcard character.

Comment: it does not have to:) `-F"?"` `-F?`  `-F'?'` and `BEGIN{FS="?"}` are equal  @glennjackman

Comment: @haifzhan glenn's point is that there could be a file called, say `-FA` in your filesystem. Then `-F?` matches the name of that file, and is transformed to `-FA`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I misunderstood it:) sorry glenn

Answer (score 0):

test.txt

```
/veratt/po/dashboard.do
/veratt/po/dashboardfilter.do?view=R
/veratt/po/leaseagent.do?view=R
/veratt/po/dashboardfilter.do?&=R&=E&propcode=0&display=0&rateType=0&floorplan=&=Display&format=4&action=getReport
/veratt/po/leaseagent.do
/veratt/po/leaseagent.do?view=V
```

command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="?"} {a[$1]++} END{for(i in a) print i, a[i]}' test.txt
```

output:

```
/veratt/po/leaseagent.do 3
/veratt/po/dashboard.do 1
/veratt/po/dashboardfilter.do 2
```

explain:

`BEGIN{FS="?"}`  set ? to be the field separator, so $1 will be the substring before the first ?. This only run once before process contents of test.txt

`{a[$1]++}`  create an array, index is the substring, make it auto-increment.

`END{for(i in a) print i, a[i]}` iterate the array, checks its index and corresponding value, the END block runs once after all lines of the test.txt processed.

Comment: @downvoter, the stackoverflow server was down for a couple minutes, so the pasting format was messed up